# Send SOAP Requests using PHP and get the returned response

Tags: php, soap

I am trying integrate a payment gateway in a simple PHP site (my own site) and the gateway accepts data only in SOAP format. I have absolutely no idea what the SOAP is, but thanks to Google I now know how it looks like (at least).

Basically, I need to send a bunch of customer data and payment data to the gateway to act according to the response receive. Here are the sample request code and sample response code. They only provided the URLto post to and that is `http://69.94.141.22/SaveTransactions.asmx`.

**Request**

```
POST /SaveTransactions.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 69.94.141.22
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendTransactionsAction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <strUserName>string</strUserName>
      <strPassword>string</strPassword>
      <strSecureKey>string</strSecureKey>
      <strFirstName>string</strFirstName>
      <strLastName>string</strLastName>
      <strPhoneNumber>string</strPhoneNumber>
      <strStreetNumber>string</strStreetNumber>
      <strUnitNumber>string</strUnitNumber>
      <strStreetName>string</strStreetName>
      <strCity>string</strCity>
      <strState>string</strState>
      <strZipCode>string</strZipCode>
      <strEmailAddress>string</strEmailAddress>
      <strBankName>string</strBankName>
      <strRoutingNo>string</strRoutingNo>
      <strAccountNumber>string</strAccountNumber>
      <strCheckNo>string</strCheckNo>
      <strAmount>string</strAmount>
      <strNotes>string</strNotes>
    </SendTransactionsAction>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendTransactionsActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SendTransactionsActionResult>string</SendTransactionsActionResult>
    </SendTransactionsActionResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How do I post these to the URL provided using PHP and how do I get that response `SendTransactionsActionResult` from the returned response?

I am not asking you to do it for me, but a simple get started like codes will help a lot.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by using [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), php [soapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) or [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

Below i have shown you how to use **NuSOAP** library

Also the WSDL is location in ***http://69.94.141.22/SaveTransactions.asmx?WSDL***

```
    $client = new nusoap_client("http://69.94.141.22/SaveTransactions.asmx?WSDL", true); // this should be the wsdl location
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    // Use basic authentication method
    $client->setCredentials("username", "password", "basic"); //set here the credentials if need for the wsdl
    $client->setHeaders('<SendTransactionsAction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                        <strUserName>string</strUserName>
                        <strPassword>string</strPassword>
                        <strSecureKey>string</strSecureKey>
                        <strFirstName>string</strFirstName>
                        <strLastName>string</strLastName>
                        <strPhoneNumber>string</strPhoneNumber>
                        <strStreetNumber>string</strStreetNumber>
                        <strUnitNumber>string</strUnitNumber>
                        <strStreetName>string</strStreetName>
                        <strCity>string</strCity>
                        <strState>string</strState>
                        <strZipCode>string</strZipCode>
                        <strEmailAddress>string</strEmailAddress>
                        <strBankName>string</strBankName>
                        <strRoutingNo>string</strRoutingNo>
                        <strAccountNumber>string</strAccountNumber>
                        <strCheckNo>string</strCheckNo>
                        <strAmount>string</strAmount>
                        <strNotes>string</strNotes>
                    </SendTransactionsAction>
                    ');
    $result = "";
    if ($client) {
        $result = $client->call("SendTransactionsAction"); // soap action
    }
    if ($client->fault) {
        echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    else {
        $error = $client->getError();
        if ($error) {
            echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<h2>zip code</h2><pre>";
            print_r($result);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
    echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
    echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
    echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
    echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the WSDL from http://69.94.141.22/SaveTransactions.asmx?WSDL, you could generate the corresponding package from [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) in order to be sure on how to structure your request in PHP as every element will be a PHP object with setters/getters. It uses the native PHP SoapClient class so you'll understand easily and quickly who to send these requests if you're familiar with PHP